# Would you be interested in having a user profile field for the link to the WordPress.org account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

On *Drupal Answers* we asked for [a user profile field to use for the link to the drupal.org account](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/can-we-add-drupal-org-username-as-a-profile-field).

I was wondering if you would be interested to a similar user profile field, and the request could not be made more generic, and valid for both the SE sites.

Comment: You mean wordpress.org, do you? If so, yes, that would be useful.

Comment: @toscho It's what I meant. I changed the title.

Comment: I personally think this is a crap idea. As it stands people come here more now since the wp.org support forums are lacking on answering topics.

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx Showing the wp.org account link has nothing to share with the wp.org forums.

Comment: But what's the point. Adding a wo.org username field is pointless. Besides I dont know about others but I tend to use my username everywhere xlrdxrevengex is all I use really

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx It depends. So far, I am not suggesting any usage of the link; I just asked if a similar field should be of interest for wordpress.SE. If nobody is interested in such field, then nobody is going to add it, which is probably what would happen if you would ask to add one, as it's a decision only Stack Exchange stuff can take.

Answer (score 3):

How it would be better than simply including that link in "about me" section if you want to?

Of course same can be said about existing "website" fields, but I don't see much point in that one either. :)

Comment: The difference is that the "about me" section doesn't reports "if you have an account on WordPress.org, report it;" if there would be a separate field, users would know they can report their WordPress.org account.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, ... No - thank you for asking :)

I'm not such a big fan of the wp.org profile pages and accounts. I fix or extend sometimes stuff at the codex, assign to a trac ticket or even sometimes publish a mini-plugin (that i not maintain then), but I really don't care about wp.org profiles.

But - as you're already asking - i'd be highly interested in having more than just one "website" field. Currently I'm linking to my github account where people can grab free open source stuff. Adding my upcoming page and maybe some project pages over there would be really nice. Best if i could name the label myself or choose from a category like *"Website: work", "Website: personal", "Website: open source"*, etc.

Comment: I think that is what [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is for :-)

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Most of the links I'd set are promotional for open source, freely available software. The point is that they are spread around the web. I got a job and don't need/want to get job oportunities via those links.